# how to query a table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Suppose we have one table in Microsoft Access:

```
ID | Data
```

I need to select one row with a SQL query in VBA code.

In what variable to store that row? How to write that row back to the table in VBA? Could you please write simple code?

Comment: @Igor: let people know you're serious: **upvote answers** to your previous questions, and **mark an answer as the 'accepted' answer**. It's the reputation system on StackOverflow.

Comment: Let me dissent on acceptance. I don't give a rat's ass if somebody who asks a question has never accepted a single answer. I only read and answer questions that interest me, and whether I can get reputation points from answering is the least interesting issue I can imagine.

Comment: @Igor: what makes you think you need to load a row in code? In Access, editing is usually accomplished via forms, and you don't have to write any code to do that.

Comment: Maybe none of the answers worked. Maybe the answers caused him to change to a different approach, to which none of the answers was appropriate. I can think of dozens of scenarios where there is no answer to be accepted for the purposes of the original questioner. That doesn't break SO because everybody else gets to vote on the answers as they relate to the original question.

Comment: That is, the original questioner's actual interests are not necessarily aligned with what is best for SO, and that should be OK.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a RecordSet object. T[his site](http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdaoadorecordsets.html) provides many examples.

Here's a an example I put together from that site. This will grab all the records from tblName and update just the first record

**UPDATE** Answer changed to use DAO which is recommended when using Access Tables.

```
Dim rs As New DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT pkPeopleID, LastName FROM tblPeople", dbOpenDynaset)

rs.MoveFirst
rs.Edit
rs![Data] = "Foobar"
rs.Update

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

If you want a specific row rather than just the first row you can add a where clause e.g.

```
 Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT pkPeopleID, LastName FROM tblPeople Where id = 123", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Or you could use FindFirst instead

```
rs.FindFirst "id = 123"
```

Comment: @Conrad Frix. DAO is native to Access and should nearly always be used in preference to ADODB. @Igor, AddNew can be used to add a record to a recordset. You can also use a query : Set db=CurrentDB  db.Execute "Insert into MyTable (MyText,Mydate,MyInt) Values ('ABC',#2010/11/25#,1)  There are many ways to skin this particular cat :)

Comment: @Remou. The link has both ADO and DAO syntax. I just grabbed one. Its been 10+ years since I've written VBA code professionally so I'm sure that you're right.

Comment: @Conrad: to make your answer useful, why not make it the more normal data access interface, DAO?

Comment: @Remou @David I took your advice and updated the answer to use DAO

Comment: Good stuff. I took "where" out of FindFirst because I reckon you had a paste error.

Comment: There's no utility in `rs.MoveFirst` when the very next statement is `rs.FindFirst`. By default, the record pointer is on the first record, but if you're using .FindFirst, you don't really care where you're starting from (though .FindFirst starts from the first row of the recordset, which is one reason to optimize it when you can to use .FindNext and .FindPrevious; but that's a topic for another time...). Now, if I weren't doing a .FindFirst, I'd explicitly set the record pointer with .MoveFirst simply because I don't like depending on default behaviors.